# Injecting content script in iFrame but not on original website

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have an extension that use an iFrame to embed a website in it, i want to inject a content script in it to modify the page inside the frame, i have managed to do that using:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://website/*"],
    "js": ["js/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "src/myScriptToInject.js"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_start"
}],
```

It works as intended but the problem is if i go now to the original website, it will naturally inject my script into it making it literally broken.

So i tried using `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {allFrames: true, runAt: 'document_start', file: 'src/myScriptToInject.js'});` but the thing is, if i understand correctly, i can not inject a script in a chrome extension for "security reasons".

Is there a way i have not thought of or a trick that would help me ?

Comment: Check `if (window != top)` in the content script to see if it's inside an iframe, otherwise don't process.

Comment: Oh wow, that was so simple, thank you very much.